# MVC5 Bootstrap datepicker compare two dates

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-datepicker

I work on Bootstrap Datepicker with textbox. I have two text boxes with a datepicker hooked up to them. The text boxes are for start date and end date. The first datepicker is setup so that the user cannot choose a date before today, but can choose any date in the future.

How can I setup the second datepicker so that it cannot choose a date before the date chosen in the first date picker?

I try this code but it not work on second textbox

```
  $("#CheckIN").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        startDate: "today"
    });
    $("#CheckIN").change(function () {        
        var endDate = $("#CheckIN").datepicker('getDate') ;    
        $("#CheckOUT").datepicker({startDate: endDate });
    });
    $("#CheckOUT").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var startDate=null;
var endDate=null;
$(function () {
    $("#start-date").datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        autoclose: true,
    }).on("changeDate", function(ev){
        console.log(ev);
        startDate=new Date(ev.date.getFullYear(),ev.date.getMonth(),ev.date.getDate(),0,0,0);
        if(endDate!=null&&endDate!='undefined'){
            if(endDate<startDate){
                    alert("End Date is less than Start Date");
                    $("#start-date").val("");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#end-date").datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        autoclose: true,
    }).on("changeDate", function(ev){
        endDate=new Date(ev.date.getFullYear(),ev.date.getMonth(),ev.date.getDate(),0,0,0);
        if(startDate!=null&&startDate!='undefined'){
            if(endDate<startDate){
                alert("End Date is less than Start Date");
                $("#end-date").val("");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thinks this will help